# How do I Iterate over IEnumerable dataSource in CreateChildControls GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

I can get the enumerator and the Current object but I don't know what the object contains so how do i iterate over a collection when you don't know the type and write out there values. Sample code would be great please

```
protected override int CreateChildControls(System.Collections.IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
    {
        // Call base method and get number of rows
        int numRows = base.CreateChildControls(dataSource, dataBinding);

        IEnumerator enumerator = dataSource.GetEnumerator();
        while(enumerator.MoveNext()
        {
            object obj = enumerator.Currnet as object;   
        }

        return numRows;
    }
}
```

Comment: What results are you seeing? What are you expecting?

Comment: this is related to my other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698008/writing-out-the-data-for-each-row-in-custom-gridview-control-and-adding-insert-r i'm not getting any results cos i don't know how to put the values into the GridViewRow

Comment: @RickNZ im from new zeland aswell in wellington

Comment: Hi from Nelson (formerly Sunny Nelson, now wet-and-muddy Nelson).

Comment: You wrote a book thats pretty good man an Apress one

Comment: What im trying to do is create a grid with a insert row at the bottom. it works if there are no records but when I create one with records it doesn't show the data just the insert row

Comment: Set a breakpoint and then look at the variable in the Visual Studio IDE's watch window.

Comment: I know theres data and it loads if I don't put the second if statement if(numRows > 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in your other question, the short answer to your question is "reflection." That's how the standard databinding tools work their magic.

Comment: can you give me a link or links to some pages that give examples

Comment: check this out http://typedescriptor.net/System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable,Boolean)

Comment: The original code is using "tentative" ("as") casts to check for various types. That's an alternative to reflection at first, but sometimes isn't enough.